# Hive unpartitioned table didn't get loaded with data

Tags: apache-spark, datatable, hive, loaded, drop

I dropped and recreated existing hive table which is not partitioned through spark job. when I ran the job first time after dropping, it didn't get loaded with data. Then I re ran the same job again with out making any changes now it is showing data.what could be the root cause why data didn't get loaded for the first time.

Comment: Check if your files are the format you think they are.

Comment: Yes they are in format . Infact same dropping and recreating we did last time then data got loaded for the first time itself.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem, i.e. make it happen? Or does it happen sometimes only? You should supply some example code.

Comment: It happens only sometimes not always

Comment: If you can't reproduce your error then no one will be able to help you.